# Type arguments cannot be applied to non-parameterized class BFTask in PFAnalytics and PFObject

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, pfobject, bftask

I've updated my project to iOS 9, my podfile, and all necessary files, but it will not build. The source of my grief is in the following error message:

`Type arguments cannot be applied to non-parameterized class 'BFTask'`

This is the only error that shows, but it shows up multiple times in both `PFAnalytics.h` and probably more importantly `PFObject.h`.

Could someone tell me what this means and please suggest a solution? I hope I have provided enough information, but if not, let me know!

[image: **Update 01:** I couldn't post the screenshot of the errors because my reputations aren't enough.]

The code samples are as follows: In `PFObject.h` and `PFAnalytics.h`, everywhere there is the following:

```
(BFTask PF_GENERIC(XXSOMECLASS *)*) someMethod;
```

the error is thrown. This is no code of mine, it is `PFObject.h` and `PFAnalytics.h` as stated before. Examples of the functions throwing the error in `PFObject.h` are below

```
- (BFTask PF_GENERIC(NSNumber *)*)saveInBackground; 
- (BFTask PF_GENERIC(NSNumber *)*)saveEventually;
- (BFTask PF_GENERIC(NSNumber *)*)deleteInBackground;
+ (BFTask PF_GENERIC(NSNumber *)*)saveAllInBackground:(PF_NULLABLE NSArray *)objects;
+ (BFTask PF_GENERIC(NSNumber *)*)deleteAllInBackground:(PF_NULLABLE NSArray *)objects;
// .... etc
```

when clicking on the stop sign the suggestion is to delete PF_GENERIC(NSNumber *), resulting in a method like this

```
 - (BFTask *)xxsomeMethod;
```

but that doesn't help as it just gets a lot messier

**Update 02:** The contents of my `Podfile`:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'

target: 'BMR' do 
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6' 
    pod 'ParseFacebookUtils', '~> 1.8' 
    pod 'Parse' 
    pod 'ParseUI', '~> 1.1' 
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.6' 
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.6'
    pod 'JSQMessagesViewController', '~> 7.2'
    pod 'IDMPhotoBrowser', '~> 1.7' 
    pod 'RNGridMenu', '~> 0.1' 
    pod 'APHorizontalMenu', '~> 1.3' 
    pod 'ASIHTTPRequest', '~> 1.8' 
    pod 'AutoScrollLabel', '~> 0.4' 
    pod 'CJAMacros', '~> 2.1' 
    pod 'CrittercismSDK', '~> 5.3'
end
```

Comment: I recently [opened an issue with the Parse-iOS repo](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/297) with the same issue.

Comment: Did you update or install any new software before you got this behavior? I updated my XCode command Line tools, installed mongodb, and yeoman, then I noticed this behavior in XCode. It could be unrelated, but it might help.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `Podfile` ?

Comment: Podfile:# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
target 'BMR' do
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6'
    pod 'ParseFacebookUtils', '~> 1.8'
    pod 'Parse'
    pod 'ParseUI', '~> 1.1'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.6'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.6'
    pod 'JSQMessagesViewController', '~> 7.2'
    pod 'IDMPhotoBrowser', '~> 1.7'
    pod 'RNGridMenu', '~> 0.1'
    pod 'APHorizontalMenu', '~> 1.3'
    pod 'ASIHTTPRequest', '~> 1.8'
    pod 'AutoScrollLabel', '~> 0.4'
    pod 'CJAMacros', '~> 2.1'
    pod 'CrittercismSDK', '~> 5.3'
end

Comment: Thanks. I added the podfile to your question to make it easier to read.

Comment: thanks. sorry about that

Comment: No problem. Is there any chance you can share your Xcode project with me privately? If privacy is a concern, you can remove anything sensitive, or I will gladly sign a NDA. I would like to compare our projects and see if I can catch the similarities. The team at Parse is having trouble finding the cause, so we need more information.

Comment: any luck? same problem here after upgrading parse

Comment: @bmurmistro, no luck so far, but I am sending the Parse team a stripped-down version of my XCode project so they can take a look at what is happening. You can [follow along with progress on github](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/297). Maybe you can join in on the conversation on github and help us narrow the problem down.

Comment: @bmurmistro, are you willing to share your project with the Parse team as well? The more data they have the faster they can solve this problem.

Comment: @radiovisual I can't share at the moment, but I can tell you that it broke somewhere between version 1.8.3 and 1.8.5. I roll back to 1.8.3 and I'm good! Also, I'm using cocoapods too.

Comment: I'd like to share my project with the Parse team as well

Comment: Looks like a solution may have been found, and the answer provided by [Cyprian](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32681016/3960969) may be the correct answer. [Refer to the issue on github](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/297#issuecomment-142766941) for more information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure that you don't have a **duplicate version of the Bolts.framework**.

If you are using both Parse SDK and Facebook SDK you will encounter a problem where Parse SDK contains an older version of Bolts (currently 1.1.5) and the FB SDK has the newest version of Bolts SDK (>= 1.2.2)

Once you remove an older version of the `Bolt.framework` that comes with Parse SDK you should be fine.

To check what version of Bolts.SDK you have simply go to the `Bolts.framework` file, right - click and choose "Get Info".

Comment: I don't install the frameworks manually. I install parse via cocoapods. Here are the relevant pods that I add:          pod 'ParseFacebookUtils', '~> 1.8'
    pod 'Parse'
    pod 'ParseUI', '~> 1.1'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.6'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.6'   When I run pod install (or update), it adds the current version of Bolts "Using Bolts (1.2.2)"   I still get the same errors

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. If you are pulling in the FacebookSDK from the framework files AND you are pulling in the Facebook-iOS-SDK via Cocoapods, then there is a good chance that you have two versions of the `Bolts.framework`, it worked for me. I was pulling in the FacebookSDK and the Facebook-iOS-SDK via Cocoapods, so as soon as I deleted the file: `FacebookSDK/Bolts.framework` the errors went away. See [the issue on github](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/297) for more information.

Comment: Here is my solution courtesy of Nikita Lutsenko. THANKS!
If you double check your `Framework Search Paths` build setting for BMR target – you will see that `/Users/xxxxx/Documents/FacebookSDK` path is there.
Even though you don’t have it explicitly added to your project – Xcode will still look for frameworks in that folder, and if it finds anything (say in our case outdated version of Bolts.framework) - it will attempt to use that in some cases.

Solution for your problem – remove that line from `Framework Search Paths` or delete Bolts.framework from anywhere in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have two `Bolts.framework`, old from FacebookSDK and new from Parse. So go to the FacebookSDK folder from where you added the `FacebookSDK` into the xcode and delete the `Bolts.framework`. Keep the new `Bolts.framework` and everything will be fine now.

If you still is not able to find the old `Bolts.framework` find the class file showing error and right click it and select show in finder and traceback the facebook folder from the finder and make sure it is in Facebook SDK folder and delete the `Bolts.framework`. Make sure you don't delete the new Bolts.framework you added from Parse SDK folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (spent a few hours investigating whats going on). I messed up old FacebookSDK framework with the one I installed via cocoapods

1. Check the following path **~/Documents/FacebookSDK** to see if there are some outdated SDK
2. Remove any import of Facebook SDK `#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>`
3. Install it via cocoapods 
    
   `pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
   pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
   pod 'FBSDKShareKit'`

   or add the new framework manually.