# Type arguments cannot be applied to non-parameterized class 'NSDictionary' when using Crashlytics 3.3.4 building against iOS 8.4 SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I've recently upgraded to Crashlytics 3.3.4 using the Fabric Mac App.

Building against iOS 9 SDK is fine. However when I try to build against the iOS 8.4 SDK, I get this:

[image]

I've tried cleaning the build folder and deleting derived data, but this doesn't help.

[Type arguments cannot be applied to non-parameterized class BFTask in PFAnalytics and PFObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673375/type-arguments-cannot-be-applied-to-non-parameterized-class-bftask-in-pfanalytic) suggests that perhaps this is caused by duplicate frameworks, but I can't see anything obvious in my frameworks folder:

[image]

Nor my Pods folder:

[image]

There's also [xcode 7 Type arguments cannot be applied to non-parameterized class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770500/xcode-7-type-arguments-cannot-be-applied-to-non-parameterized-class) which states a similar problem, but there's no answers as yet.

Something which may or may not be important -- I'm using Xcode 7.0.1 and when I build against iOS8.4, there's two devices listed:

[image]

However, no matter which device I select when building, I always get the "Type arguments cannot be applied to non-parameterized class 'NSDictionary'" error.

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to solve this problem by simply installing earlier versions of Crashlytics (e.g. 3.1.0) and Fabric (e.g. 1.2.8) via Cocoapods.